# How to use the default typewriter font with Times New Roman?

Tags: fonts, verbatim, typewriter, times

I'm trying to use the default typewriter font (that comes with LaTeX & CMU) with Times New Roman.

[image]

If I disable the `newtxtext` package, I can use the nice typewriter font, but it disables Times New Roman for normal text and math mode. It's a small yet noticeable difference.

[image]

Is it possible to get both TNR for text and this nice typewriter font?

MRE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\title{Font Tests}

\begin{document}
Here is some text without the typewriter font. \texttt{Here is some using it.} Below is code in a verbatim block.
\begin{verbatim}
(define x 5)
\end{verbatim}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While it's ok to immediately upvote answers you find to be adequate, site guidelines strongly recommend waiting *at least several hours*, and maybe even a day or two, before "accepting" any particular answer you find to be "best." That way, you don't discourage other users from posting additional, and possibly superior, solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works with PDFlatex :

Add `\renewcommand{\ttfamily}{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont}` in the preamble.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\renewcommand{\ttfamily}{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{lmtt}\selectfont}
\title{Font Tests}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Here is some text without the typewriter font. \texttt{Here is some using it.} Below is code in a verbatim block.
\begin{verbatim}
(define x 5)
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

(I have also moved the `\maketitle` and `\section{Introduction}` right after the `\begin{document}`).

Result:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't loading the `newtxtext` package with the option `nott` be an easier and more transparent solution?

Comment: @Mico Yes, you're right (I didn't kwow it). But my "solution" works also with other main font document loaded by a package. So this can be usefull in others situations. However, your solution is better for the OP specific question.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want? Run it with `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\begin{document}
Here is some text without the typewriter font. \texttt{Here is some using it.} Below is code in a verbatim block.
\begin{verbatim}
(define x 5)
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to change the default monospaced font when using the `newtxtext` package, just load the package with the `nott` option:

```
\usepackage[nott]{newtxtext}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nott]{newtxtext} % <-- note: "nott" option

\begin{document}
Here is some text without the typewriter font. 
\texttt{Here is some using it.} 
Below is code in a verbatim block.
\begin{verbatim}
(define x 5)
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```